# Adding Unit tests for functionality that no longer exists

Tags: c#, unit-testing, software-design

We are involved in quality assurance and as part of this process, we perform reviews on code that is written by a third-party development company.

One of the team members raised a comment against some unit tests that had been written off the back of a functional change to existing code. Ordinarily, this would be expected and normally we have to raise comments about these tests not being added or updated.

The functional change in question was to completely remove 2 methods. This was not a change to add selective logic that would mean it would not run in some scenarios, it was deleted, completely.

The developer in question added unit tests, that included setting a single expectation on a WCF service mock and asserting that it was not called.

In some ways credit was due , but in our opinion the unit test was completely redundant and added no value and therefore the comment was raised and the tests were removed. Subsequent discussions about this and it has ultimately landed on my desk as a post implementation discussion point.

I tend to be in agreement, what is the point of testing code that is not even there. Where do you draw the line, surely if you start down that route, you need to do 'everything', but what is that, what does it look like.

One of the feedback comments was that it was implemented as negative testing, but to me that is still aimed at testing code that exists, but simply trying to break it by passing in unexpected parameters.

Curious as to what other's opinions were.

Comment: This question belongs to another site on Stack Exchange: [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could very well argue for such kinds of tests, especially in security related scenarios.
Assume that the removed methods where made public accidentally and they open up a security hole.
Removing them is important and it would be a regression if they would re-appear. In other words: Removing those methods was the way that the security hole was fixed and as such, tests are warranted.

On the other hand, if nothing was fixed by removing those methods - they might have been removed because they were deprecated - no tests are necessary.

Comment: Good points. The code in question was not public, but did occur during the workflow of a another public method. Basically, it sent 2 requests to another service, those requests were no longer needed and therefore deleted. So we are not fixing anything, simply removing behaviour 'completely'